# Choosing the Right Resource Bundle : JAVA SE 8

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have below 3 properties files

**RB_en.properties**

```
ride.in=Take a ride in the
```

**RB_en_US.properties**

```
elevator=elevator
```

**RB_hi_IN.properties**

```
elevator=lift
```

---

**My system Default Locale is :=**
en_US

---

**My code is**

```
// BundleTest.java
import java.util.*;

class BundleTest {
    public static void main(String ... args){
        Locale l = new Locale("hi","IN");
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("RB",l);
        
        System.out.println(rb.getObject("ride.in") + " " + rb.getObject("elevator"));
    }
}
```

---

**Expected Output** :=

```
Take a ride in the lift
```

---

**But I am getting below error:=**

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key ride.in
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
        at BundleTest.main(BundleTest.java:9)
```

Comment: you failed to define the resource "RB". Read carefully the API description example then you know how to create the resources from ListResourceBundle. That is why you got the exception saying the missing key ride.in

Comment: The default resource bundle should contain all values in a default language.